# NSIS read files in folder and run exe's

Tags: nsis

I need the code to read the contents of a folder then run each exe it finds in the folder, exe will change name and will be added and removed as needed. I want this so I do not have to update the code each time I add or remove programs.

something like this:

read ".\data\programs*.exe"
ExecWait ".\data\programs*.exe"

so if there are 10 exe's then it will run each one for a total of 10 installs
so if there are 8 exe's then it will run each one for a total of 8 installs

how can I do a read or get for all the files and put into a var, as some of them I will need to do a check and if it equals a particular filename I want it so run with switches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Locate](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/AppendixE.html#locate). Something like:

```
!include "FileFunc.nsh"

Section
    ${Locate} "$INSTDIR\my-exes" "/L=F /M=*.exe" "MyExec"

    IfErrors 0 +2
    MessageBox MB_OK "Error" IDOK +2
    MessageBox MB_OK "$$R0=$R0"
SectionEnd

Function MyExec
    ExecWait '"$R9"'

    Push $0
FunctionEnd
```